# Need alternative way to deal with LDOs minimum current requirement

Tags: microcontroller, voltage-regulator, low-power, ldo, linear-regulator

I am designing a circuit that uses an LDO to produce 3.3v from a 10 to 18v input.
I sometimes will need 1.2 amps from this regulator and at other times I only need microamps. When I need even less I can shut down the regulator but there will be times when I need regulation and my circuit will only draw possibly .5 or 1 milliamp. My circuit contains a microcontroller.

My datasheet says my LDO requires 5ma minimum load. It's a Micrel/Microchip MIC29150.

So my question is, other than putting a resistor on one of the GPIO pins of my micrcontroller and burning off electricity at around 5ma when I want to, are there any other techniques I can use that are better?

One of my thoughts were to put a zener in series with a resistor so that if the voltage goes over 3.5 or so that it burned off some milliamps but that seems dangerous to me.

Comment: So what's the problem with putting a 680 ohm resistor from the output of the regulator to ground (not one of the GPIO pins) and let it waste 5mA?

Comment: It's not dangerous but if you are always going to be taking 5 mA you might as well use a standard regulator especially as your supply has tons of headroom and doesn't need an LDOR or do what Jim says.

Comment: regulating 1+ Amp over 7~15V difference from input, sounds like you could use a buck converter..

Comment: Small LDO + buck converter that can be switched on and off?

Comment: @JImDearden: I thought about a buck converter instead. But it's noisier. The reason I need to turn this on and off is because I can disable the LDO and the circuit needs to only pull microamps. It will be living on a supercap charge potentially for days. The uController will wake up every few hours to check a few things and then put itself back into deep sleep.

Comment: " It will be living on a supercap charge potentially for days" Didn't you consider that this information was critical to the question and should have been included. We can only answer a question on the basis of information provided.

Comment: @JImDearden - I put this line in the question "When I need even less I can shut down the regulator" - So that's why I didn't feel it relevant to the question. This regulator doesn't have much leakage backflow from out to in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the datasheet for the MIC29150:

> The MIC2915x–2975x regulators are specified between finite loads. If
>   the output current is too small, leakage currents dominate and the
>   output voltage rises. The following minimum load current swamps any
>   expected leakage current across the operating temperature range...

So it seems the minimum load requirement is determined by the worst case leakage from IN to OUT through the LDO. 5mA seems like a lot - the leakage is probably far less than this in most cases. Also, leakage is a very strong function of temperature, so if your application will not see high temperatures you could get away with less.

A zener at the LDO output might also be an option, as you stated. This will prevent the output of the LDO from exceeding the zener breakdown voltage in the case that the leakage current is greater than the load. In this case you would want to check that your load can survive the zener voltage, and also make sure that there is no overlap between the regulation voltage of the LDO and the breakdown of the zener - that would cause the LDO to dump current into the zener.

Personally, I would recommend looking for a different LDO that doesn't have such an onerous minimum load requirement. There are many with no minimum load requirement at all.

Answer (score 2):

Most LDOs with minimum current requirements do so for stability. With too little current, the control loop may not have enough gain, or it may lose phase margin and get unstable.

Perhaps try to find a regulator which does not have such a requirement?

Check MIC2940A and MIC2941A

You could also use a switching regulator...

Comment: I chose that regulator because it has automotive load dump and reverse connection features I like. I will look at those others.

Comment: Unfortunately, the MIC294x datasheets say this:

The MIC2940A will remain stable and in regulation with
load currents ranging from 5mA on up to the full 1.25A
rating.

Comment: It also says "The minimum recommended load current of 1µA" for MIC2941 so.... I wonder which one wins!

Comment: That's weird. I'm going to go ahead and prototype this thing and find out more.

Comment: Those ICs are huuuge.

Comment: Well, since you got 18V in, 3.3V out, and 1.2A max current, dissipation would require a TO220, so I filtered on that.

Comment: Yes, thank you - but that current is short-lived and I'm derating the part a lot and am using the SMD part with thermal vias to several layers. I almost think I should use the buck regulator, but I didn't want to add another inductor to the circuit.

Comment: OK! Well, if you're only pulsing the 1amp current you could get away with DPAK regulators... Weird thing is you worry about wasting 5mA, but not about the super low 18% efficiency when converting 18V to 3V3 ?...

Comment: When my circuit has 13v on it, it's running on a charging car 12v system. Lots of current there. But it also has to be able to shut down and sleep and not draw any current once shut off. It won't have access to the 13v then and must stay active (via the supercap) for sometimes a week or so, possibly longer.

Comment: OK! That makes sense. What voltage do you have on the supercap?

Answer (score 2):

[MCP1703](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22049e.pdf) is specified up to 16V (tolerates 18V), has a \$<10\ \mu{A}\$ quiescent current and ground current \$<0.15\ mA\$ under maximum load conditions.

If you need it, you can drop some volts using series diodes at the input.

Comment: Yes. But only 1/4 amp. :(